# Multiple photos stabilization

Tags: lightroom, post-processing

I have taken 3 photos of the same subject jumping. But, unfortunately, I moved a little while doing this. Is it possible to crop my 3 pictures so the background won't seem to move? I can use lightroom and photoshop but I don't know how to do so.

Comment: As a possible alternative, have you tried a reshoot of the subject/scenario using a tripod (or other stable mount) and remote control shutter?

Comment: Mit was on holidays in another country. It was improvised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to do this is stacking the 3 images as layers, and then setting some transparency to them, so you can move them a bit.

I would use the keyboard to move them one pixel at a time and using a zoom of 100 or 200%.

There is a feature that could help: Edit > Auto-align layers

Always work on a copy of the files.